# Why is Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer() completing after one of the subscribers cancels the subscription and how to avoid it

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have come across a behaviour I don't understand when using `Sinks.Many<String>` to notify some events to multiple subscribers:

```
fun main() {

    val sink : Sinks.Many<String>  = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer()
    val flux = sink.asFlux().log()

    val d = flux.subscribe {
        println("--> $it")
    }

    sink.emitNext("1", Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)

    val d2 = flux.subscribe {
        println("--2> $it")
    }

    sink.emitNext("2", Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)
}
```

This code shows the first subscriber getting the values 1 and 2, and the second subscriber getting 2. So far so good:

```
11:49:06.936 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onSubscribe(EmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
11:49:06.938 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - request(unbounded)
11:49:06.942 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onNext(1)
--> 1
11:49:06.942 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onSubscribe(EmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
11:49:06.942 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - request(unbounded)
11:49:06.943 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onNext(2)
--> 2
11:49:06.943 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onNext(2)
--2> 2
```

Now, assume the first subscriber disposes (cancels) its subscription after the first emission, I was expecting the first subscriber to get 1 and the second to get 2:

```
    val sink : Sinks.Many<String>  = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer()
    val flux = sink.asFlux().log()

    val d = flux.subscribe {
        println("--> $it")
    }

    sink.emitNext("1", Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)

    d.dispose()

    val d2 = flux.subscribe {
        println("--2> $it")
    }

    sink.emitNext("2", Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)

}
```

```
11:51:48.684 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onSubscribe(EmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
11:51:48.685 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - request(unbounded)
11:51:48.689 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onNext(1)
--> 1
11:51:48.689 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - cancel()
11:51:48.689 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onSubscribe(EmitterProcessor.EmitterInner)
11:51:48.689 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - request(unbounded)
11:51:48.690 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.EmitterProcessor.1 - onComplete()
```

However, when the second subscriber tries to subscribe the flux is considered completed. Why is this happening? I need the Sinks.Many to be available at any moment to be subscribed and unsubscribed without cancelling.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just hit the same issue.

It is caused by autoCancel defaulting to true. Unfortunately the [onBackpressureBuffer javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.MulticastSpec.html#onBackpressureBuffer--) makes no mention of it.

This behaviour is inherited from [EmitterProcessor.create](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/api/reactor/core/publisher/EmitterProcessor.html#create--) where it is documented.

To set the autoCancel flag to false it's necessary to use the alternative [onBackpressureBuffer](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.MulticastSpec.html#onBackpressureBuffer-int-boolean-)

```java
Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false);
```

Comment: I was just doing basic research on Sinks after noticing some odd behavior in my POC. This just saved me hours of troubleshooting. The Sinks interface for `MulticastSpec` fails to link details but does have a hint for `autoCancel` - `should the sink fully shutdowns (not publishing anymore) when the last subscriber cancels`

Comment: The most bizarre aspect is how the sink keeps accepting emissions despite being cancelled. Must be a bug.